# PHP Simple form with IF Statement

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and currently working on developing my first form. With the below code sample I am trying to achieve two things.

1. If the fields for "name" or "email" are filled out in the form, then it will post "Your name is: "name" and "Your email is:"email".
2. If a field is not filled out, then it will display nothing at all.

I believe this needs to be done with an IF statement but I am having a hard time finding anything showing the protocol for if the field is empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form action="Test.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 

$name = $_POST["name"];
if($name="name") {
    echo "Your name is: $_POST["name"]" ;
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
<br>

<?php 
$email = $_POST["email"];
if($email = "email") {
    echo "Your email is: $_POST["email"]" ;
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have multiple PHP syntax errors... you canNOT use `"` quotes within a `"`-quoted string, nor are you allowed to use quoted array keys within `"`-quoted strings. Your if() tests are doing ASSIGNMENTS (`=`), not testing for equality (`==`). Basically, you need to study basic PHP syntax a bit more.

Comment: All you need is `echo "Your name is: " . $name;` etc. If you want to check if a name was entered, `if(!empty($_POST['name']))` or `if(isset...` - Wait for the answers to roll in...vvvvv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional statements are incorrect.

You're presently making an assignment using `=` with `($name="name")` and `($email = "email")` when you should be checking if something is "equal to" using `==`.

Also, as [`Marc B stated in his comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668492/php-simple-form-with-if-statement#comment32753336_21668492): ***"you can NOT use `"` quotes within a `"` quoted string, nor are you allowed to use quoted array keys within `"` quoted strings..."***

However, if you were to keep that strategy; i.e.: `if($name=="name")` then your form would only work if the words `name` and `email` were entered in the form's inputs.

There are a few ways to achieve this, checking if a field is (not) empty using `if(!empty` or if it is set `if(isset`.

In this case, I used `if(!empty`. Meaning, that if the fields are not empty, then echo the results afterwards.

**This is a basic example:** (There are other ways to achieve the same result)

```
<form action="Test.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "Your name is: " . $name;
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
<br>

<?php 
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    echo "Your email is: " . $email;
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to write:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="Test.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(!empty($_POST['name']))
    echo "Your name is {$_POST['name']}. <br />";


if(!empty($_POST['email']))
    echo "Your email is {$_POST['email']}. <br />";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S.: I really recommend reading an introductory book, at least to cover the basic functions. After that you can go directly to php.net and look for functions on-a-need basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset) to check if the variable is actually set. You could also use [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/empty) to check that it exists and if there's a value stored. For example:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email')) {
    // do things
}
```